# Compiling issue DSharp and Spring4D

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, spring4d

I was trying to compile DSharp framework and Spring4D, but got some issues with not compatible versions between these versions.

I am wondering which revisions need to use for building these frameworks.D etails below, these versions are not compatible between itself:

- Spring4D - release 1.1 (2014-09-13)
- DSharp - feature/caliburn (2014-10-09);feature/spring4d-compatibility (2014-10-02); latest from develop/master
- Delphi - XE7

Comment: Please also include the generic tag `delphi`. This is needed for syntax highlighter and draws more attention on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSharp feature/spring4d-compatibility works with Spring4D 1.1 (we are using that in production)

TreeViewPresenter also works but that one requires the VirtualTrees package and should work with the latest version. Once we release Spring4D 1.2 I will make sure DSharp works with that one aswell and merge it back to develop.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was able to build together (in one BPL package) following versions of frameworks under XE7:

- Spring4D - release 1.1 (2014-09-13)
- DSharp - feature/spring4d-compatibility (2014-10-02);

I have not included only TreeViewPresenter to this combined BPL.

PS. Yesterday I was trying to build the same but under XE7 update 1

Comment: Checked under XE7 upd1 - also compiled as described above.